# Is it possible to get a warning if return value is not used?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I have an extension method which returns a value. In this case, it should set a specific bit in a byte:

```
public static byte SetBit(this byte b, int bitNumber, bool value)
{
    if (value)
    {
        return (byte)(b | (1 << bitNumber));
    }
    return (byte)(b & ~(1 << bitNumber));
}
```

The returned value needs to be assigned to a variable again, because I cannot combine `this` and `ref`:

```
byte myByte = 3;
myByte = myByte.SetBit(1, false);
```

It is easy to forget the assignment by accident. Someone might think that the method changes the value directly.

For a `String.Replace`, ReSharper/Visual Studio<sup>(?)</sup> is warning me that the  *Return value of pure method is not used*:

[image: String]

Is this also possible for my method in some way?

Comment: "The returned value needs to be assigned to a variable again, because I can not combine this and ref"  Really?  I just tried, and it worked fine...

Comment: `ref this byte b` won't compile for me @KirkWoll

Comment: Alternatively, write a [Roslyn Analyzer](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/How-To-Write-a-C%23-Analyzer-and-Code-Fix) -- it's a great way to enforce certain patterns for your code-base.  You can even write it so it's embedded into your solution -- great for company-specific projects.

Comment: Ah, I see what you were trying to do.  Yeah, that won't work, but you could _still_ provide a seprate `ref` parameter if you were inclined. (Or better, probably, make it an `out`)  That being said, writing the Roslyn analyzer is probably better.  There's nothing wrong with expecting consumers to realize the type operates immutably -- see the methods on `string` for example.  But admitedly, it is often a source of confusion to beginners.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Update:*

Now there is a [`PureAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute?view=net-5.0)  in the `System.Diagnostics.Contracts` namespace.

```
[Pure]
public byte Foo()
{
    //...
}
```

---

*Pre .NET Standard 2.0 Answer:*

There seems to be a Nuget Package for [ReSharper Annotations](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JetBrains.Annotations/).

This includes a [`MustUseReturnValueAttribute`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#MustUseReturnValueAttribute):

```
[MustUseReturnValue("Use the return value to...")]
public byte Foo()
{    
}
```

As @Kirk Woll pointed out in the comments, it is also possible to write a custom [Roslyn Analyzer](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/wiki/How-To-Write-a-C%23-Analyzer-and-Code-Fix.md).

Comment: Was about to post similar, but tested it and [it works](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EY7nt.png) exactly as described.  (I used `[Pure]` rather than `[MustUseReturnValue]`, but I presume they work the same)

Comment: `[Pure]` and `[MustUseReturnValue]` are very similar in effect. `[MustUseReturnValue]` allows specifying a custom message, but other than that, the main difference is semantic. `[Pure]` means that the method makes no changes to the state of the object (so the only reason for calling it is the return value). `[MustUseReturnValue]` also means the return value is important and should be used, but makes no guarantee about the state of the object.

Comment: It would be nice to get this Warning by Default, just like in F#, since about 99% of my functions return a Value that should be used (otherwise calling it would be useless). Most Functions (should) have no side effects and are therefore even [Pure]. Does anyone know a way to enable this Check by Default?

Comment: It seems that someone have already written such Roslyn Analyzer:
https://github.com/cezarypiatek/CSharpExtensions

Comment: @Spoc and WojciechKałuski - What you describe is also available as a built-in Microsoft analyzer rule: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76801296/3442232

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to being notified in general about return values being unused and not explicitly discarded, you can use the Microsoft code analysis rule https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0058

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out if being notified about unused returned values from every method, you can either use the [Remove unnecessary expression value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0058) MS code analysis rule or the analyzers from [CSharpExtensions](https://github.com/cezarypiatek/CSharpExtensions)

If you prefer to get *a warning only when the return value of explicitly specified methods is ignored*, consider checking out the [MustUseRetVal](https://github.com/mykolav/must-use-ret-val-fs) analyzer.

It emits a diagnostic if it comes across code that ignores the value returned from a method marked with `[MustUseReturnValue]`

For example

```cs
[MustUseReturnValue]
public bool IsGrantedDatabaseWritePermission() {
   // ...
}

// Elsewhere in your code:
// The value returned from `IsGrantedDatabaseWritePermission` must be
// assigned to a variable or checked in an if statement, etc.
// Otherwise, the analyzer will emit an error.
var isGranted = IsGrantedDatabaseWritePermission();
if (isGranted)
    WriteToDatabase();
```