# Shared method to return string only if needed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a method that is shared between two other methods which do the same thing, both post events to outlook calendar but in one case I don't need the response string returned, here is the method:

```
private static async Task<string> InitPost(Kalender kalender, string email)
        {
            using (Client)
            {
                var postUri = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{email}/calendar/events";
                var httpContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(kalender), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var method = new HttpMethod("POST");
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, postUri)
                {
                    Content = httpContent
                };
                var response = await Client.SendAsync(request);
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return responseString;
            }
        }
```

Is it possible to call the method like so: `await InitPost(KalenderEntity, email);` or does it have to be `var e = await InitPost(KalenderEntity, email);`?

if possible, can someone explain what happens with the return string? I am new to coding and what I have learned in school is that if you have a method with a return type then you have to "catch" it.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757545/is-it-possible-to-get-a-warning-if-return-value-is-not-used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to "catch" the returned value, it's fine to ignore the return value of the method. But, in some cases this might be a warning sign of a bad design that is, if it's possible that the two callers, are using the same method for two different things, you should split your method into two different implementation.

Comment: You're right and this way it's more inline with SLOID principles, I will split the method. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can leave `await InitPost(KalenderEntity, email);` if you don't need a result, it's ok. In this case, you don't assign the result of this method to any variable and it will be removed from memory by GAC.

Comment: GAC inspects randomly right? It's gonna be a problem for performance in that case, I think I will follow Mahmouds answer and split the method. Thanks!

Comment: I guess that there won't be performance problems, any way you allocate memory inside your method's body. But it's better to do as Mahmoud said for better code structure.