# c#: warning if results discarded

Tags: c#, warnings

I've had several timewasting bugs from my mistakes where the result of an expression is not used, so is silently discarded, something like this

```
x.something(...)
```

instead of the intended

```
var y = x.something(...)
```

This is trivial to catch and I want the compiler to do so. If I really want to throw away the result I'd be happy to cast to void or use a discard (`_ = something()`). Is there any way of it catching such silly mistakes? If so, are there other checks I can enable as well that may prove useful?

Comment: Yes, add a rule to a .editorconfig.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1806

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757545/is-it-possible-to-get-a-warning-if-return-value-is-not-used, but I really don't like the current answer

Comment: @gunr2171: wasn't aware of this. I added "dotnet_diagnostic.CA1806.severity = error" to my .editorconfig per canton7's url, copied in the 'Book'  sample from there that was supposed to trigger it, nothing shows up. The compiler's still not complaining. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3779002 That's part of a new suite of diagnostics for .NET 5 IIRC. Are you targetting .NET 5? IIRC there might be a way of enabling them for lower language versions provided you're using the .NET 5 SDK. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/overview#code-quality-analysis) and the sections that section links to

Comment: @canton7 Using VS 2019. Looks like I've got .net4 installed. I'm writing a kind-of transpiler so I'm just using C# with little else, not 'targetting' anything. I could try to upgrade but 100% huarantee something will break if I do and I'd rather save the time and do something productive instead. I can live without it for now, may experiment upgrading in a VM later (but VS runs very, very badly in a VirtualBox I've found).

Comment: @user3779002 Are you using an old-style project or an SDK-style project? If you're using an SDK-style project, then see what SDKs you've got installed with `dotnet --list-sdks`. You can be compiling using the .NET 5 SDK, but still building an application which runs on the .NET 4 Framework

Comment: @canton7 Hi and thanks. Did, got 3.1.302 & 3.1.402 so I guess not. I'll live with this rather than dare try and upgrade. But thanks, and you've given me some reading to do!